# Realtime node.js app vs. mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, real-time-updates

I have a node.js app that polls every x seconds a mongodb database to show data variations.

I think there must be a better way to do it, using all the capabilities of node.js environment ... which is the most efficient way to trigger mongodb data variations and showing them using node?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a tailable cursor

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-tailable-cursor/